# How to get binary data from javascript in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, blob

I want to access binary data (blob) from javascript in Django. I tried using a form and using the blob url, but this doesn't seem to work on the Django side.

Here is my blob in javascript:

```
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
document.getElementById("id_bloburl").value = blobURL;
```

The id_audiofile is in a form that gets then submitted to django. In Django I tried accessing the data from the blob url using:

```
bin_data_url = form.cleaned_data['bloburl']
//download the file from bin_data_url
```

But it seems empty. Any ideas how I can get the blob in Django correctly?

Answer (score -1):

Can you use ajax? I would go with base64 encoding and json (didn't really test):

On the javascript side:

```
$.post(url, {data: $.base64.encode(blob)});
```

On the Django/Python side:

```
import base64
import simplejson

class BinaryView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        json = simplejson.decode(request.raw_post_data)
        base64.b64decode(json['data'])  # perhaps just the blob in base64?
```